# Problema sobre consulta en base de datos de mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

**Hola a todos, espero que estén bien.**

Estoy cursando bases de datos 1 en la facu y actualmente estamos dando MySql.

---

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio, el cual no logro resolver al 100%: "11. Obtener para cada inmueble la renta total obtenida. "

Estas son las tablas de la base de datos con la que estamos trabajando:

[image: Tablas de la base de datos]

Hasta ahora llevo la consulta de esta manera:

```
SELECT CodInm, Precio*CantDias AS RentaTotal 
FROM inmueble NATURAL JOIN alquiler;
```

**Como resultado obtengo lo siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi drama es que necesito agrupar todos los inmuebles por código y que sus valores de RentaTotal queden sumados.

Espero que se entienda el problema y que puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ponele un SUM para sumar los totales

SELECT SUM(CantDias * Precio) as Renta
....

y al final

GROUP BY inmueble.codInm

Comment: Impecable bro, me imaginaba que me faltaba un pequeño detalle, lo del group by lo tenía en cuenta pero no sabía como sumar los valores luego. Muchas gracias por colaborar!

Comment: @AlexisVelázquez si la respuesta satisface la pregunta inicial, debes marcarla como aceptada.